# compile-time function for checking type equality

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I need to implement self contained compile-time function for checking type equality (function template without arguments `bool eqTypes<T,S>()`).

self contained means not relying on library.

I'm not good in all this. That's what I tried, but it's not what I need.

```
template<typename T>
bool eq_types(T const&, T const&) { 
return true;
}

template<typename T, typename U> 
bool eq_types(T const&, U const&) { 
return false; 
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3450395/168175 shows how to implement it yourself, but it would need (trivially) adapting to be a function instead of a struct.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's quite simple. Just define a type trait and a helper function:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
bool eqTypes() { return is_same<T, U>::value; }
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e579b7d68ba42805cfde5a309e2a23e5-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

In C++11, if you are allowed to use `std::false_type` and `std::true_type`, you would rewrite the above this way:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool eqTypes() { return is_same<T, U>::value; }
```

Notice, that the type trait [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), which does pretty much the same thing, is available as part of the Standard Library.

Comment: Might as well `constexpr bool eqTypes()`.

Comment: @TimothyShields: True, I was assuming C++03 was the target. I will add  a C++11-ish version

Comment: @liuml07: Can you elaborate on your statement? I'm not sure what you mean here

Comment: @AndyProwl I don't know the expected answer of the `eqTypes<Base, Derived>()`. I suppose it be `true`. The `std::is_same` can't work for this either. If the expected answer is `false`, it looks good.

Comment: @liuml07 Are you talking about a `base *` and a `derived *` returned by `typeof` on two pointers pointing to the same `derived` object? Those are indeed different types, so I'm not sure I would say it "doesn't work". What about a `void *` and `int *` both pointing to an `int`, would you expect that to return `true`?

Comment: @liuml07: `eqTypes<Base, Derived>()` should return `false` indeed. That's supposed to check whether the types are *equal*, not whether one is convertible to the other, or derived from the other, and so on - there are other type traits that serve those purposes

Comment: @AndyProwl: Right. It's straightforward to return `fasle` on second thought.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can do it in C, without any magic GCC extensions:

```
#define CHECKED_TYPE(original_type, p) ((conversion_type*) (1 ? p : (original_type*) 0))
```

E.g:

```
void *q = CHECKED_TYPE(int, &y);
```

Will trigger a compile error if `y` is not `int`.
For explanation, see [here](http://trust-in-soft.com/compile-time-consistency-checks-for-types-in-c/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CHECK_TYPE_EQUAL(type_a, type_b) { \
    type_a type_a##_var __attribute__((unused)); \
    type_b *type_b##_ptr __attribute__((unused)); \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic error "-Wincompatible-pointer-types\"") \
    type_b##_ptr = &type_a##_var; \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop") \
}
```