# If-else based on which typedef is being used

Tags: c++, typedef, typeof

I've seen similar questions to this on SO but haven't found an answer for what I'm looking to do. I have two typedefs, only one of which will be used (other will be commented out):

```
typedef Student StudentType;
typedef StudentPF StudentType;
```

I want to use the alias `StudentType` for whichever one I'm currently using. Later on I have two different sets of code and I want to pick which set to run depending on whether `StudentType` is a `Student` or a `StudentPF` (Student taking course as Pass/Fail).

Is there a way to have something to this effect?

```
if (StudentType is of type StudentPF)
    //do these things
else
    //do these different things
```

The reason I'm attempting to do this is so I can change the behavior of my program just by simply commenting out one line and commenting in another if I keep the headers for both `Student` and `StudentPF` included.

Comment: I think you should go for static/dynamic polymorphic solution for this kind of issue. You can also look for strategy pattern

Comment: @RakibulHasan is correct; dispatching on the type of the object is a bit of an anti-pattern and is usually a symptom of a poor design. However, if you insist on doing this, you can (a) use a traits class or (b) use RTTI or (c) just add a method to each object that returns an `enum` designating its type.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about having an object.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924168/compile-time-function-for-checking-type-equality It requires heavy (as in advanced) templates.

Comment: @RakibulHasan Just looked up the strategy pattern that does seem very useful and more elegant than what I have going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function template. Specialize it for each of the types you are interested in. Instantiate it with your typedef type.

```
template<typename T>
void DoStuff();

template<>
void DoStuff<Student>()
{
    ...
}

template<>
void DoStuff<StudentPF>()
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    DoStuff<StudentType>();
}
```

Comment: Cool idea seems like it would easily solve my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, `Student` and `StudentPF` aren't entirely interchangeable.  So they ought to have something in their public interfaces letting you tell them apart.  Maybe something like:

```
class Student {
public:
    constexpr static bool is_pf = false;
    // ...
};

class StudentPF {
public:
    constexpr static bool is_pf = true;
    // ...
};

void my_func() {
    if (StudentType::is_pf)
        ;
}
```

But if you can't change `Student` or `StudentPF`, there's always:

```
#include <type_traits>
void my_func() {
    if (std::is_same<StudentType, StudentPF>::value)
        ;
}
```

Neither of those will work if the code in the `if` or `else` clause won't compile for the "wrong" type.  In that case, you would need some sort of static dispatch function.

Comment: Both seem like good ideas and I've never seen that type_traits class, something to keep in mind

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) for this :

```
if (std::is_same<StudentType, StudentPF>::value)
    //do these things
else
    //do these different things
```