# Check for template type parameter, during compile time, for type specific operation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

First of all, the code is restricted to C++11, so I cannot make use of *if constexpr*

Following is my sample code snippet:

```
class A{
 public:
    int a;
    int b;
}

class B{
 public:
    int key;
    int val;
}

class C{
 public:
    int n1;
    int n2;
}

class D{
 public:
    int n1;
    int n2;
}

class E{
 public:
    int n1;
    int n2;
}

template<typename T>
void func1(T data) {
   if (T == type(A)) {             // Just pseudo template-check code
    std::cout<<data.a<<data.b;              //<------1
   } else if (T == type (B)) {    // Just pseudo template-check code
    std::cout<<data.key<<data.val;          //<------2
   } else {
    std::cout<<data.n1<<data.n2;            //<------3
}


int main() {
A a;
B b;
C c;
D d;
E e;

func1(a);
func1(b);
func1(c);
func1(d);
func1(e);

return 0;
}
```

Currently, I get a compile-time error at,

```
1: B,D,E,F has no member a & b
 & 
2: A,D,E,F has no member key & val
 &
3. A, B has no member n1 & n2
```

I tried using [is_same()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/) & also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16924234/10106284), but I get same compile time error every time.

1. I cannot make use of C++14/C++17
2. How could I make use of specialized template functions?

Edited the code to highlight the need of a template.

Comment: Which part of what you're trying to accomplish cannot be done by old-fashioned, straightforward, specialization?

Comment: A relatively realistic usage, including a `main` would be tremendous, because so far I see no reason to do anything but provide two different functions. `std::cout<<T.a<<T.b; ` is pure fantasy; it isn't remotely valid code. There are no arguments to `func1`, so the caller is entirely  responsible for providing `A` or `B` as a template argument at call-point. If you're going to do that, you may as well have two different functions to call in the first place, be they specialization or otherwise.

Comment: After your update, now ask yourself why template any of this *at all* ? Why not just use `func1` with two overloads: `void func1(A data)` and `void func1(B data)` ?

Comment: In your example you don't need templates at all. Just define 2 overloads of func1.

Comment: how much genericity do you need? The answer you got is fine for `A` and `B`. It would be possible to make it work for any type, but is it worth?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function overload and avoid the function template altogether.

```
void func1(A a)
{
   // Type dependent code.
}

void func1(B a)
{
   // Type dependent code.
}
```

A function template makes sense only if there is common code for all the types for which the function call is made. If you have some code that is common to all types and some code that are type dependent, then you can use:

```
void func1(A a)
{
   // Type dependent code.
}

void func1(B a)
{
   // Type dependent code.
}

template <typename T>
void func2(T t)
{
   // Type independent code.
}

template <typename T>
void func(T obj)
{
   func1(obj);   // Call function that uses type dependent code.
   func2(obj);   // Call function that uses type independent code.
}
```

Comment: why did you introduced `fun2`?

Comment: @MarekR, to show how type dependent code and type independent code can be split.

Answer (score 1):

You must write specializations of the function for the two types your want to use it with.

```
#include<iostream>

class A{
 public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class B{
 public:
    int key;
    int val;
};

template<typename T>
void func1(T);

template<>
void func1<A>(A arg) {
    std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<arg.a<<arg.b;
}

template<>
void func1<B>(B arg) {
    std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<arg.key<<arg.val;
}

int main(){
A a;
func1(a);

B b;
func1(b);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple overload does the job.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void func1(T data)
{
    std::cout << data.n1 << data.n2;
}

void func1(A data)
{
    std::cout << data.a << data.b;
}

void func1(B data)
{
    std::cout << data.key << data.val;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r7Ee6E
Tweaked a bit: https://godbolt.org/z/xxPWaE