# Getting Return Type of Callable Type in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a template class with a callable type-parameter `<typename Callable>`.

I know that `Callable` indeed creates a callable object, and is often a lambda.
In my particular case, I also know the number (arity) and type of arguments (just one).

How can I get the return type of this callable type `Callable` on VS2010?

Comment: What about `decltype()`?

Comment: Oh never mind, I see what you're asking -- you need to get the return type of a generic lambda, am I right?

Comment: @Jashaszun: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Do you know the types of the arguments that `Callable` is supposed to be called with?

Comment: @Brian: Yes. One arg of a known type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various approaches, but support for C++11 in VS2010 is only partial and most approaches simply didn't compile.

What did finally work (on VS2010) is the following:

```
// When arity is known
typedef decltype(callbackInstance0())            return_type0; 
typedef decltype(callbackInstance1(argInstance)) return_type1;
```

Where `callbackInstanceX` is the actual callable object to be used and `argInstance` is the actual arg to be passed to `callbackInstance`.

Note that this is not a general solution (though sufficient in my case) because:

- It cannot be used outside of a function where you don't have actual instances of these types, but only the types, as in the class definition;
- The callable arity must be known.

Answer (score 4):

See [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Pretending the object is invoked with one `int` argument, you could do things like:

```
using return_type = typename std::result_of<Callable(int)>::type;
```

Comment: I tried using `std::result_of` but this particular usage doesn't seem to work on VS2010. Even with a regular `typedef` instead of the `using`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't generally possible.

There are multiple ways to have callable types, including lambdas and `struct`s that overload `operator()`.

C++ does not have nearly the type of reflection that languages like C# do, and it is impossible to do with the tools that C++ offers.

If all you want is to store the result of that "callable" into a variable, then you can just use `auto`.

If you actually want to do stuff with the result based on its type, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450327/type-equality-test-w-decltype-auto-or-rtti-in-c-does-boost-have-somethin) might help.

Basically, add this to your code.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct same_type 
{
   static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct same_type< T, T >
{
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

Then, if you have `auto result = func(param);`, where `func` is of type `Callable`, you can check the type of `result` with the following:

```
if (same_type<decltype(result), int>().value)
{
    // code, knowing that result is of type int
}
else if (same_type<decltype(result), const char*>().value)
{
    // code, knowing that result is of type const char*
}
// else if ... etc.
```

Comment: Exactly. Hence my problem. `auto` will not help here as I need to conditionally use the result, but not to store it.

Comment: Check out my edit. I tested it and all, and it works! :)

Comment: Please don't `if` based on a compile-time type.

Comment: Will this work when the result type is `void`? This is a common case.

Comment: @AdiShavit It will not, because `void` is not a type. I don't think any solution can work correctly with `void`.