# C++ templates check the type and use some specific function

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any mechanism to detect the type of `T` in the function and choose the correct method to execute?

I know that I can write several functions like `ClassContainerAdv<INT OR FLOAT>::` but I don't like this way, because the original function is 100 lines of code and I need to choose correct method only at one line. So, if I will have two `ClassContainerAdv<INT OR FLOAT>::` functions -- this means `2x` bust of the same code (copy&paste) on the source file.

Example:

```
template <class T>
void ClassContainerAdv<T>::add_data_to_sqlite( const sqlite3* db )
{
[skip]
if ( T == "INT" ) 
        sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 1, (it->first) );
else if ( T == "FLOAT" ) 
         sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, (it->first) );
[skip]
}
```

Comment: @Jashaszun That's only checking if multiple template classes are equivalent.

Comment: @Josh It's barely one step further to check for type equality.

Comment: `[skip]... anotherFunction<T>(stmt, it->first);...[skip]`

Comment: @vlastachu `anotherFunction<T>()` still needs to be specialized for certain types of `T`.

Comment: NO seems solution by the link only for functions with different get parametrs `func(string s) func (int s)` etc. I have Class<type> and fucntion that always get ( const sqlite3* db ) as a parametr

Comment: Write a subroutine, overloaded for each type, that you call from `add_data_to_sqlite` when the dispatching is needed.

Comment: @abrahab Well, you could make use of RTTI, comparing `typeid(T)` values.

Comment: @quantdev yes, I thought about it. Seems it's easier that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450327/type-equality-test-w-decltype-auto-or-rtti-in-c-does-boost-have-somethin

Comment: if overloading might be lead to ambiguity consider `enable_if`

Comment: So, I need to call `SomeFunction(T);` on the original template function and made two versions of overloaded `SomeFucntion(int)` and `SomeFucntion(float)` for `binding`. Yes?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand. The problem in question is 100 lines of code which should be copy-pasted in specialized function.

Comment: @vlastachu _'I understand.'_ I'm afraid you didn't. Your proposal isn't that bad at all, I just stated, it needs to be specialized to be useful. You provide another templated method, have a default implementation, that just fails (best at compile time), and have templated specializations for this method, binding to the right `sqlite3_bind_<T>` functions. These specializations will be narrow in the actual case, in general replicating larger pieces of code operating on specializations is a bad idea, yes.

Comment: Using C++11 u can use static_assert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the good old set of overloads for the parts that diverge :

```
// Some overloads
void bind(int i);
void bind(double d);
// etc...

template <class T>
void ClassContainerAdv<T>::add_data_to_sqlite( const sqlite3* db )
{
[skip]

bind(x); // x is double, or int or ...

[skip]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specialize your function template. For example:

```
template<typename T>
void ClassContainerAdv<T>::add_data_to_sqlite( const sqlite3* db );

template<>
void ClassContainerAdv<int>::add_data_to_sqlite( const sqlite3* db )
{
    sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 1, it->first);
}

template<>
void ClassContainerAdv<float>::add_data_to_sqlite( const sqlite3* db )
{
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, it->first);
}
```

Comment: yes, I know. I wrote about it at the original question. The problem that original function is huge. And there will be tons of copy&paste on the source if I will do that. But yes, it's look easy to do.

Comment: @abrahab _'The problem that original function is huge.'_ If the differences boil down, to the `sqlite3_bind_<T>` calls, separate these out (refactor!) from the boiler plate stuff (`[skip]`).

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your code (from [Type equality test w/ decltype(), auto, or RTTI in C++? Does Boost have something for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450327/type-equality-test-w-decltype-auto-or-rtti-in-c-does-boost-have-somethin)):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct same_type 
{
   static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct same_type<T, T>
{
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

Then you can check the type like this:

```
template <class T>
void ClassContainerAdv<T>::add_data_to_sqlite(const sqlite3* db)
{
    if (same_type<decltype(T), int>().value) 
        sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 1, it->first);
    else if (same_type<decltype(T), float>().value) 
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, it->first);
    // else if ... etc.
}
```

Comment: That's very unsafe. The compiler still has to compile both branches despite the truth of the conditions. You'll get a compilation error if you call a function inside the branches where the parameter type isn't convertible to the actual type of `T`.

Comment: Unfortunately you have close voted for duplication the same time. From a strategical point, you might better retract your close vote, and link the dupe with your answer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Would you please explain more? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I linked the somewhat-dupe, but is it possible to retract a close vote? (I didn't think of the exact specifics before voting to close.)

Comment: I know it's offtop: Why there should be a `struct`? Why not do the function `int is_same(){return false;}`

Comment: When the function is instantiated, `T` is replaced with the type provided. There's no threat in this code specifically, but if you had code that depended on a specific type of `T` in one of the branches you risk a compiler error if `T` is not the type that it requires.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm still not sure that I understand. How would `T` *not* be the type that that branch requires? It was just checked for!

Comment: @Jashaszun _'but is it possible to retract a close vote?'_ Of course, just click the [close link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171101/c-templates-check-the-type-and-use-some-specific-function#) again, and the dialog offers you to retract.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have a close link. (< 3k rep) I never cast a close vote -- I only flagged it.

Comment: @Jashaszun Ah, sorry. I tend to forget the exact rep privileges echelon.

Comment: @Jashaszun [Please see this example.](http://rextester.com/CTGX46563)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ok, now I understand. I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to get it to not emit the error through the use of `auto`, casting, etc., but no luck. Do you have any suggestions (besides to not use this method)?

Comment: @Jashaszun Template specialization like in my answer.